# WebGL drawElements not drawing anything

Tags: dart, webgl

Consider the following code sample.

```
Float32List positions = Float32List.fromList([
    0.0, 1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0,
    1.0, -1.0
]);

gl.bindBuffer(WebGL.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
gl.bufferData(WebGL.ARRAY_BUFFER, positions, WebGL.STATIC_DRAW);

Uint32List indices = Uint32List.fromList([
    0, 1, 2
]);

gl.bindBuffer(WebGL.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
gl.bufferData(WebGL.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices);

var a_pos = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "a_pos");

gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_pos, 3, WebGL.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_pos);

gl.clearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
gl.clear(WebGL.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

gl.drawElements(WebGL.TRIANGLES, indices.length, WebGL.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

Foregoing the usual setup of a canvas, context, shaders etc. the method `drawElements`does not work. Nothing shows up on the screen.

To sanity check, I've also written this code without the element array buffer and drawing the triangle with `drawArrays` instead. When using `drawArrays`, the triangle shows up as expected. This tells me there should be nothing wrong with my shader code.

What could I be missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the element array is of type `Uint32List`, then the draw command has to use the type `UNSIGNED_INT`. Note, while `UNSIGNED_SHORT` indicates an element array of 16 bit unsigned integers, `UNSIGNED_INT` indicates an array of 32 bit unsigned integers.

```
gl.drawElements(WebGL.TRIANGLES, indices.length, WebGL.UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Comment: Turns out this was indeed the issue. It's weird that I missed this the three times I re-typed my own project and even converted an example JavaScript project to a dart project. Thanks for the sanity check.